# MvvmCross - should we implement NSCoder-based constructors in views

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, mvvmcross, xib

According to [latest Xamarin.iOS documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/ios9/#UIView_fails_to_init_with_coder_when_loading_a_view_from_a_XibNib) there is step to improving compatibility in Xamarin-based code:

> UIView fails to init with coder when loading a view from a Xib/Nib
>
> **Reason**: The initWithCoder: constructor is the one called when loading
>   a view from an Interface Builder Xib file. If this constructor is not
>   exported unmanaged code can’t call our managed version of it.
>   Previously (eg. in iOS 8) the IntPtr constructor was invoked to
>   initialize view.
>
> **Fix**: Create and export the initWithCoder: constructor like this:

```
[Export ("initWithCoder:")]
public YourClassName (NSCoder coder) : base (coder)
{
    Initialize (); // refactor initialize code into a method
}
```

Question is: do we need to add a NSCoder-based constructors to all our UIViewControllers in MvvmCross iOS application or not.

What I see right now is that this constructor is being called earlier than expected by the MvvmCross stack.

Wondering what MvvmCross community thinks about this?
[MvvmCross github uses NSCoder only for Mac-based views](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/search?q=NSCoder&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: I don't think this really belongs as a Question on SO. But rather in the GitHub issues. Please consider creating an issue there with this information.

Comment: Was waiting for this comment. Community on SO is wider, that is why decided to ask here.

Comment: I this something related to just mvvmcross? I think that can be the case in every custom view